# Get getFeatureId from a VectorGrid.Protobuf layer on click event

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles

The vector Tile come from geoserver. I want to get the id when I click it and use it to send WFST to geoserver (WFST requires fid).

````
                var vectorTileOptions = {
                    LayerName: Layer.NAME,
                    layerImg: Layer.IMG,
                    rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                    tms: true,
                    interactive: true,
                    getFeatureId: function (f) {
                        return f.id;
                    },
                    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                        [Layer.STYLENAME]: Layer.STYLE
                    }
                };
                var vectorTileLayer = new L.vectorGrid.protobuf(Layer.URL, vectorTileOptions).addTo(FeatureGroup);
                vectorTileLayer.on('click', (e) => {
                    this.latlng = e.latlng
                    console.log(f.id)//do something
                    var properties = e.layer.properties;
                    var popupcontent = this.getPopupContent(properties)
                    L.popup({ className: 'featurePopup' })
                        .setContent(popupcontent)
                        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                        .openOn(this.map);
                });
            })```
````

Comment: Instead of logging `f.id` on layer click (which does not exist, since `f` does not exist there), log `e.layer.id`. That should be feature id you are looking for.